# ajax json.stringify request convert from string to element php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have this problem, part of my Ajax JSON.stringify arrives like text, and the other part like array element, my question is how can I covert all to an array and extract elements values, here is the code I'm receiving in my PHP script :

```
    array (size=3)
    'JSON' => string '  {
    "requestType":"TourListRequest",
    "data":{
    "ApiKey":"12345",
    "ResellerId":"1000",
    "SupplierId":"1004",
    "ExternalReference":"10051374722994001",
    "Timestamp":"2013-12-10T13:30:54.616+10:00",
    "Extension":{
     "any":{
    }
   },
    "Parameter":{
    "Name":{
      "0":" "
     },
    "Value":{
    }
    }
   }
  }
   ' (length=412)
   'URL' => string 'api_test_json.php?test=JSON Tour List' (length=37)
   'Type' => string 'JSON Tour List' (length=14)
```

MY QUESTION: How can I get the values of "requestType","ApiKey","ResellerId", etc. As PHP variables?

THIS IS THE CODE FROM I GENERATE THE AJAX CALL :

```
<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 300px;" id="request_json">
{
    "requestType":"TourListRequest",
    "data":{
    "ApiKey":"12345",
    "ResellerId":"900",
    "SupplierId":"904",
    "ExternalReference":"10051374722994001",
    "Timestamp":"2013-12-10T13:30:54.616+10:00",
    "Extension":{
     "any":{
      }
     },
     "Parameter":{
     "Name":{
     "0":" "
      },
      "Value":{

      }
     }
    }
   }
```

```
 <script>
 function SubmitAPI(){
var sendInfo = { JSON: $('#request_json').val(),
    URL: $('#supplier_api_endpoint_JSON_Tour_List').val(),
Type: 'JSON Tour List' };
       $('#response_json').html("Calling API...");
   $.ajax({
    url: "post_JSON.php",
        data: {data: JSON.stringify(sendInfo)},
    dataType: 'html',   
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data)
      $('#response_json').html(data);
      }
    });
      }
     </script>
```

Thank you in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to decode the JSON and access the variables from the resulting object data.

```
$array = ...; // the array you dump in your example
$obj = json_decode($array['JSON']);
// request type information
$request_type = $obj->requestType;
// here is all the stuff in 'data'
$data = $obj->data;
// now access your data variables like
echo $data->ApiKey;
echo $data->ResellerId;
// and so on...
```

It is the `json_decode()` step that does most of the work here.  JSON is just a serialization method for object and/or array data. Once you deserialize it via `json_decode()` you can directly access whatever data structure was serialized into JSON as you would any normal numerically-indexed array or `stdClass` object (PHP's default object type).

Note that you will oftentimes see `true` passed as a second parameter when using this function.  This converts the JSON object structure to associative arrays rather than `stdClass` objects.  I personally rarely use this as, a lot of times it seems, the items inside object structures `{}` should be treated more as objects in PHP rather than more map-like associative arrays.  Nevertheless, people who work in PHP oftentimes have a preference towards using associative arrays for some reason, so you will see this in examples a lot (like `json_decode($json, true)`)

Comment: Hi, thank you Mike for your response, but I'm still stucked. As you can see from in the array from 'JSON' it's all text, so I cannot get the elements value. I tried  echo $data->ApiKey; but I receive a NULL value. If I try this with 'URL' or 'Type', it works, because are elements of the array. Any other idea ?

Comment: Hi Mike, again me, sorry, your're right, it is working this way!! Thank you very much for your HELP ...

Comment: @CaribeSoft Yes `json_decode()` is the key. I updated answer with more context.